# Python time interval delay variable

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, xpath

I written a script to scrape google search results[Text, Link, Description] using Python. The code is working great, but i need a small tweak in the code to avoid google to analyse the HTTP requests Patterns . Here is the code

```
        #import requests
        #import json
        #from os.path import exists
        from selenium import webdriver
        #from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
        #from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
        #from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
        #from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
        import time
        #from lxml import html
        from scrapy import Selector as s
        #import os
        import csv
        import itertools

        lister = ['https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=MOT+in+Godmanchester&num=10',
'https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=MOT+in+Godmanchester&num=10&start=10',
'https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=MOT+in+Hanley+Grange&num=10',
'https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=MOT+in+Hanley+Grange&num=10&start=10',
'https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=MOT+in+Huntingdon&num=10',
'https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=MOT+in+Huntingdon&num=10&start=10',
'https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=MOT+in+March&num=10']
        #a = range(1,3348,1)
        #start = 0
        driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        with open("C:\Drive F data\Google\output.csv", "ab")as export:
            fieldnames = ['link','text1','text2','text3']
            writer = csv.DictWriter(export, fieldnames=fieldnames)
            writer.writeheader()
            for serial,eacher in enumerate(lister,start=1):
                link = (eacher)
                time.sleep(6)
                driver.get(link)
                time.sleep(3)
                print serial,'.'+link
                source = driver.page_source
                source1 = s(text=source,type="html")
                text1 = source1.xpath('//h3[(contains(@class, "r")) and not(contains(@style, "line-height:normal"))]//text()').extract()
                text2 = source1.xpath('//h3[(contains(@class, "r")) and not(contains(@style, "line-height:normal"))]//@href').extract()
                text3 = source1.xpath('//span[@class="st"]').extract()
                for each,each1,each2 in itertools.izip(text1,text2,text3):
                    each = each.encode('utf8')
                    each1 = each1.encode('utf8')
                    each2 = each2.encode('utf8')
                    #print each, each1, each2
                    writer.writerow({'link':link,'text1':each,'text2':each1,'text3':each2})
                #writer.writerow({'link':link,'text1':text1,'text2':text2})
            """
            r = requests.get("https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=MOT+in+Ampthill&num=10")
            source1 = html.fromstring(r.text)
            text1 = source1.xpath("//h3[@class='r']")
            print text1
    """
```

On line 34 i inserted a delay of 3 seconds , but i want this delay to be a variable ranging from 10 to 30 with intervals as 2 .range(10,30,2)

so that when the script executed the first delay will be 10 then 12 then 14 then 16 & so on till 30, & after reaching 30 it should come back starting from 10 then 12 then 14 & so on.

Please see the script & provide useful suggestions / modifications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just put a random number into your `sleep()`? Google will probably catch on to your sequence method.

```
from random import randint

# ..your code..
random_int = randint(10, 30)
print('Sleeping for {} seconds'.format(random_int))
time.sleep(random_int)
```

Now each request will sleep for a random amount of time, much harder to detect.

Comment: Thanks nivix , using randint function, How can i see the sleep time used ?

Comment: May be i can add 
timenow = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
& on line 35 , i can use - print serial,'.'+link,timenow

Comment: Do you want to see the number of seconds sleeped each time? Or do you want to see the timestamp before and after?

Comment: I want to see the number of seconds it slept time each time.

Comment: Edited the question to print the time slept each time.

Comment: I also added snippet to login gmail at top, randit + logged-in browser , its working great, hit 1700 links with no IP blocks & captcha till now. Thanks nivix , i wasn't aware of randint function. I was looking for range with fixed intervals. but you provided more advanced solution . Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
...
time.sleep(random.choice(range(12,31,2)))
```